# External CSS file not working alongside bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra

I am trying to add custom styling to my web app. Here is the link to my code:

https://github.com/SammyAbukmeil/rps-challenge

In `layout.erb` I have the following:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
  ...
</head>
```

Which should be loading my `custom.css` file.

In `views/index.erb` I have an ID of test:

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block" style="margin-top: 40px" id="test"src="http://i.imgur.com/hSuFTzO.png">
```

and in `css/custom.css` I am calling that ID:

```
#test {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't apply my custom styling, although bootstrap (which is being linked in `layout.erb` and is adding styling to the `.erb` files throughout the project) is working.

I've tried looking through similar questions on stack overflow without success, also tried google for how to add custom styling to a bootstrap project - everything I'm doing seems to be correct.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: So i checked the console and found this:

```
...
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Request URL: http://localhost:4567/css/custom.css
...
```

So I guess I'm not linking it right.

Comment: Check your console for errors, check Resources to make sure the CSS file is loaded properly, finally, check that your style window to make sure it's not run over by bootstrap's styles.

Comment: @odedta Thanks, just realised it has a `Status Code: 404 Not Found` So i'm obviously not linking to it properly.

Comment: Validating your code is good practice, I recommend validating your code in every step of the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sinatra any static files (such as CSS files) should be in the folder pointed to by the `public_folder` setting. Usually this is named `public`. In your `server.rb` you set it to be `public` but relative to the projects root.

You need to create a `public` folder at the top level of your project (next to `app`, `view` etc.), move your `css` directory to it and then change the setting in `server.rb` so that `:public_folder` points to it, similar to what you have done with the `:views` setting:

```
set :public_folder, proc { File.join(root, "..", "public") }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap selectors are very specific, for example `body > div > img.img-responsive`. You need to be more specific in order to override the selector. You can test this by using temporally the `!important` declaration:

```
#test {
  margin-top: 50px !important;
}
```

If it overrides, you have a working setup that just needs more specific selectors. After that you should remove the `!important` declaration and add details to the selector:

```
body > div > img#test {
  margin-top: 50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First You need to understand the hierarchy of CSS
You Can use Firebug (Firefox) to identify that your styling is apply or not also what class is overrating your custom css.

Note: Also avoid adding ID for CSS Styling

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the bootstrap selector.
It is not good practice to use this in your finished website, however you can use `!important` to over ride other style rules.

**Example of Use**

```
.element-class{
    width:50%;
}

.element-class{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

The element would have the width of 100% here.

Read more about when to use this on the [css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)